# How to setup child templates by default

Tags: templates

I'm trying to see if I can setup child templates, on a given parent template, that would show up every time the parent template is used to create an item. I tried adding the child templates to the template item itself, which it allows you to do, but after saving and refreshing the tree I created a content item using the modified template but the child items where not present. I tried this on the Standard Values item as well but no cigar. Is there some trick to this or is it just not possible?

Comment: Are you referring to branch templates, in which a tree of items are created?

Comment: I didn't know what branch templates were until I read Richard's response, but it sounds like just the thing I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

welcome to SSE.

If I'm understanding your question right, it sounds like you need to use branch templates to do this.

A branch template will allow you to set a predefined tree structure, like a parent item with 1 or more child items. Then you would setup your insert options so that instead of inserting a new item based on the parent template, you would insert a new item based on the `Branch template`

When that item is created in the content tree, the child items will also be created.

#### Creating a Branch Template

To create a branch template, navigate to `/sitecore/templates/Branches` and you can start there. Add a new `Branch` and the wizard will ask you to select the item template you want to base the branch off.

[image: Create Branch Template]

[image]

Now create your structure:

[image]

Once you have done that, set the insert options to insert the new `Branch` you created, and it will automatically create all the child items too.

Comment: This sounds like just the thing I need. Tomorrow first thing I'll try it out, if it works as expected I'll mark this as the answer. Thanx!

Comment: This is working like a charm, thanks again Richard!